# How to modify WindowState when the Form is not visible

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to be able to set `WindowState=Normal` while `Visible == false` but stepping through the code reveals it is reset to `Maximized` just after setting `Visibility = true`.

This is the smallest sample to reproduce the behavior. The actual task is to click a button on a maximized form and have it 'restore' to a different location and size than `RestoreBounds` without first restoring then resizing and relocating. It is visually distracting. Of course, it works just fine with the visibility changes commented out.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

1. Run app
2. Maximize form
3. Click button

The form will flash but still be maximized. I've tried manually setting the bounds with `SetDesktopBounds`, using `Show`, `Refresh` and even using `BeginInvoke` on the visible = true call just to make sure the underlying message pump gets a chance to process.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing battle with the way windows work natively.  Winforms goes out of its way to make it *look* like WindowState and Visible are separate properties, but they are not under the hood.  It takes a single winapi call to change both, somewhat inevitably the last one wins.

This can be tinkered with by making that winapi call yourself.  Like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int state);
    private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
```

And modify your Click event handler:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Visible = false;
        ShowWindow(this.Handle, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.Visible = true;
    }
```

Which does what you want.  Although the property assignments now seem superfluous, it is very important that you keep them and ensure they match the ShowWindow() argument you pass.  The property setters change some internal flags that are used to keep up the illusion that Visible and WindowState are unrelated.  I can't guarantee that this hack won't cause trouble.

Comment: Thanks. I had missed using both together. So close yet so far.

Comment: Test form must just be fast enough to make it look like this works. When implemented in full code, the flash of the previous `DesktopBounds` is still there. Ended up using `Opacity` instead of visibility and achieved what I need to. Thank you for your time though.